# Bootstrap shift modal footer button to left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I want to have the cancel button to the left of the footer and stay the close and save button always on right.

I have tried adding float:left property to cancel button but that didnt help. Any solution thats based on bootstrap classes are highly appreciated.

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add [`me-auto`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#auto-margins) class to your cancel button.

`me-auto` means *margin end auto* and this has the same effect than adding `margin-right: auto;` to your cancel button.

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary me-auto" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap the Close and Save buttons in a div, and set a `justify-content: space-between` in your `modal-footer` class like this:

HTML File:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

   <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS File:

```
.modal-footer {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Yes - or add the `justify-content-between` class if it's Bootstrap 5.
REF: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: Thanks for this, But I prefer a bootstrap class to be added rather inline or document css